# Using MessagePort API for Samsung Gear Apps

Tags: javascript, ipc, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I want to create an App communication with the MessagePort API between two of my Gear apps.
Based on the "Basic Project" template I have added some lines of code to open a `LocalMessagePort` and a `RemoteMessagePort`.

```
window.onload = function () {

var localMsgPort = tizen.messageport.requestLocalMessagePort('MessagePortA');
var remoteMsgPort = tizen.messageport.requestRemoteMessagePort('RKlH7XellU.Demo', 'MessagePortB');
var watchId = localMsgPort.addMessagePortListener(...);

};
```

But at runtime I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tizen.messageport.requestLocalMessagePort')
```

Do I need any additional includes or something else?

Do I have to add more privileges or features in the `config.xml` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on device, emulator or web simulator? what SDK are you using?

Comment: I tried this on real device.

Comment: Have you tried to start debugging console and then check is there tizen and tizen.messageport object with properties?